# placing a router-view in template as a sub template this isn't working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I place a route view in a template my vue router doesn't load the content, how can I load this?

In my homepage I've got

```
<router-view name="homepage"></router-view>
```

The code gets loaded perfectly from my vue router but the  contained in the homepage template doesn't get loaded.

```
...
routes:
    [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'homepage',
            components: {
                homepage: HomepageTemplate,
                subPart: subPartTemplate
            }
        }
]
...
```

homepageTemplate:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view name="subPartTemplate"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the component `subPart` but are referencing to it as `subPartTemplate`;

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view name="subPart"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Edit:** I see you edited your post; what's going wrong is you are using a child `<router-view>` without defining children in your routes;

You should define children in your path:

```
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'homepage',
        component: HomepageTemplate,
        children: [
            { path: '/', component: subPartTemplate }
        ]
    }
```

Now the `<router-view>` in the `homepageTemplate` should be the `subPartTemplate`. No need to use named components for this. Named components are useful when you need multiple `<router-view>`'s in one template.

Checkout the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) for more details.

Comment: Tried, but still can't get the it to work, the div which should contain the sub template html remains empty. I'll run trough the docs again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Managed to get this working! your solution is valid, thanks, There was an issue with my vue configuration.